# Is There A Way To Say "Fro" (as in afro/fro) In Traditional Chinese?

Tags: word-requests, sentence-structure, simplified-characters, traditional-characters

Are there any kanji that could be used to say afro and/or fro in traditional Chinese? If not, what about simplified Chinese? What are the characters?

Comment: Kanji is the Japanese term for Chinese characters. I think you mean characters.

Comment: If there are characters in traditional Chinese that fit the meaning you want, then there must be characters in simplified Chinese that also fit this meaning . . . Moreover, it's unclear if you just want the _sound_ in question or if you want a specific meaning (e.g. the hairstyle, or "to and fro").

Answer (score 1):

Simplified Chinese“爆炸头”
Traditional Chinese“阿福羅頭，爆炸頭”

Comment: When you say "Simplified" and "Traditional", I take it you mean "Mainland" and "Taiwanese" Mandarin?

Comment: Yes.In the mainland, Simplified Chinese is used.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Traditional characters are also used in Hong Kong.

Comment: @Danger14 My point is that is that the answer provided an additional work in the traditional, not present in the simplified. Maybe "阿福羅頭" is in common usage in HK... maybe not. Maybe it's in common usage in Taiwan... maybe not. It's not a meaningful claim to say that it's the translation "in Traditional Chinese"--which is simply a character set.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete I read your question to only mean the character sets. I'll read whole thread better next time. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to "爆炸頭”, you can also say "爆炸裝".

Answer (score 0):

I think the question has been misunderstood. Do you want the syllable 'fro' or the name of the hairstyle?

I don't think the syllable 'fro' can be represented in Chinese. You might approximate with 'folo' = '坲咯‘, 'afro' could then come out as 'a fo lo'='啊坲咯‘.

There is no syllable 'fro' or 'flo' in Chinese. I am often very amused when I see Chinese representations of English words. Makes you wonder what the Chinese are hearing. Does 'jia na da' sound like 'Canada'? Just came across this one, guess what it is: 'ying te er'

Then again, Chinese tones are a book with seven seals for me. 'hao' always sounds like 'hao' to me, whatever tone the exasperated teacher tries to teach me!

Comment: To express the syllable "fro" in Chinese, I would use “fo2luo4/fu2luo4 佛洛”  or “fu2luo4 弗洛” such as in Erich Fromm (弗洛姆), Robert Frost (佛洛斯特) or Sigmund Freud (弗洛伊德).